# Project Euler 8 largest adjacent 13 digit product

Tags: python

Project Euler problem 8.  It works for 4 digits but not 13.  I have researched this topic but I haven't found any solutions!
The incorrect number I'm getting is 5377010688.

```
import pyperclip
import math
import urllib2
import re
import string

def adjacent_product(length):
  response = urllib2.urlopen('http://projecteuler.net/problem=8')
  html = response.read()
  m = re.search(r'<p style="font-family:courier new;text-align:center;">(.*?)</p>',html,re.DOTALL)
  numbers = m.group(1)
  numbers = string.replace(numbers,'<br />', '')
  number_list = numbers.split('\n')[:-1]
  new_numbers=[]
  for numbers in number_list:
    numbers = string.replace(numbers,'\r','')
    new_numbers.append(numbers)
  number_list = new_numbers[1:]

  product_max=1

  for number in number_list:    
    for i in range(0,len(number)-length):
      product = 1
      for n in range(0,length):
        product*=int(number[i+n])
      if product>product_max:
        product_max=product
  pyperclip.copy(product_max)
  print product_max
adjacent_product(4)
```

Comment: You (and we) might find troubleshooting easier if you split up the code to extract the data from the website from the code to process it.

Comment: I thought I did that with an extra newline.

Comment: @JakeHm it would be better if you split it into two functions, then you could just show us `number_list` and the code to process it. It is worth noting that the correct answer spans two rows of characters - how does your code deal with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you misunderstood the question: This is *one 1000 digit number*, not a list of several numbers.

Change your loop:

```
for number in number_list:
```

to this:

```
number = "".join(number_list)
```

Your code works for the 4-digits case because that `9989` can be found in the middle of a line, but it fails for 13 digits, since the highest number sequence spans from the fourth to the fifth line.

---

Also, with `number` holding the entire number as one string, you can simplify your code to this:

```
max(reduce(operator.mul, map(int, number[i:i+n])) for i in range(len(number)-n+1))
```

Comment: Oh.  That is easy then.  It says "adjacent" in the problem so that threw me off.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider make your `number_list` a real number list, and not a list of strings of digits:

```
number_list = [int(char) for number in number_list for char in number]
```

after that you can find the solution taking every quintuple of number_list and multiply the number int the quintuple. Then take the max:

```
from operator import mul

quintuples = (number_list[i:i+5] for i in xrange(len(number_list) - 4))
results = (reduce(mul, quintuple) for quintuple in quintuples)
return max(results)
```